# Regex is not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex :

```
new RegExp("^[a-z 0-9\"\-\`]+$", "ig")
```

and I'm testing a string which is not suppose to work : `'#vc'`

But it does pass the test : ( and it shouldn't (`#`))

```
new RegExp("^[a-z 0-9\"\-\`]+$", "ig").test('#vc') //true
```

But if I remove either `\"` or `\-` or `` \` ``, it does work ( and test fails as it should).

What am I doing wrong ?

My regex simply search for English , numbers , space , ["],[-][ and [`]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `RegExp` constructor, you need to **double up the escaping**, since there are 2 layers of escaping: escaping in JavaScript string literal and escaping in the regex syntax.

However, in your case, it is possible to write a regex without escaping at all.

In your case, you can just use **literal `RegExp`**, in which you only have to care about escaping in regex syntax, and escaping for any `/` that appears in the regex (since `/` is used as delimiter for literal `RegExp`:

```
/^[a-z 0-9"\-`]+$/gi
```

Another way is:

```
/^[a-z 0-9"`-]+$/gi
```

**You don't need to escape dash `-` if it is the last in a character class**. This way, you don't need to confuse yourself with all the escaping.

Or if you still want to use `RegExp` constructor, you need to double up the escape to specify `\` in the string:

```
new RegExp('^[a-z 0-9"\\-`]+$', "ig")
```

Or just use the other version where `-` is specified last in the character class:

```
new RegExp('^[a-z 0-9"`-]+$', "ig")
```

Note that I change the string quote from `"` to `'` to avoid having to escape `"` in the string. If you for some reason prefers `"`, escape `"` at the literal string level:

```
new RegExp("^[a-z 0-9\"`-]+$", "ig")
```

---

As for your current regex

```
new RegExp("^[a-z 0-9\"\-\`]+$", "ig")
```

is equivalent to

```
/^[a-z 0-9"-`]+$/gi
```

**As you can see a character range from `"` to `` ` `` is included**, which means all characters with ASCII code from 0x22 to 0x60 are included, and `#` happens to be in the range.

To check whether the pattern is what you want, you can always call `source` property of the regex to obtain the source string of the regex.

Comment: I can't believe I failed with  that... :-0

Comment: but look here http://i.stack.imgur.com/guafm.jpg it fu** up everything ( in visual studio)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You don't need to escape `"` inside character class. You only need to escape it once, if your literal string quote is `"`, and you can avoid that if you use `'` to quote your literal string.

Comment: I know . just asking. I failed with `"` so i surly want to know if i do it correctly.... :-)

Comment: so if i wanted (still though not needed)to escape it and use `"` as a wrapper so : `new RegExp("^[a-z 0-9\\\"\\-\\`]{0,100}$", "ig")`....correct?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Correct, but redundant. Removing the redundancy: ``"^[a-z 0-9\"\\-`]{0,100}$"``. Why don't you just use literal RegExp? It is less confusing.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: If you write your regex normally (in the forms where you only need to care about regex escaping), then performs string literal escaping, it will be less confusing. Same for the reversed process: print out the `source` of the regex with `console.log` (not just access it, you need to print it), then you will obtain the plain regex and you can ignore the escaping done in the string.