# javascript regex shows "Nothing to repeat "?

Tags: javascript, regex

[**I have this simple regex**](http://jsbin.com/adadiv/6/edit) which search a specific pattern :

it searches a specific string which ends /**or not** with `*`

```
var g= new RegExp("^" + 'required' + "[0-9]+(\*?)", "i");
alert(g.test('required123'))
```

I dont understand what's the problem here. It seems that the `(\*?)`  is causing an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must escape the `\` in a string literal :

```
new RegExp("^" + 'required(?!TT)' + "[0-9\.\-\_a-z]+(\\*?)", "i");
```

This makes `\*` in the regex, which seems to be what you want if you aim to test if the string has  `*`.

Comment: why do i have to escape it twice ?  I didnt have to do it in the `[0-9\.\-\_a-z]`

Comment: @RoyiNamir Normally you'd have to, but the slashes aren't actually necessary inside the character class if you replace it with `[0-9._a-z-]`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g but how will it know that `-` is not specifiying a range ?, anyway I dont understand why i have to escape it twice

Comment: Warning : This answer might be not complete, as I don't get the goal and logic of the regex. But for the `*` part it looks to be correct.

Comment: @RoyiNamir If `-` appears as the first or last character inside a character class, it's understood to be a literal `-` character rather than a range.

Comment: @dystroy a `word+number+..` which can or can not end with an asterix.my whole question is about the ending asterix which is fails at console. Ive edited the regex to be simplier)

Comment: I forgot i already had an answer about that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15496718/859154 ( and i asked it...) _If you use RegExp constructor, you need to double up the escaping, since there are 2 layers of escaping: escaping in JavaScript string literal and escaping in the regex syntax._

Comment: OK. But I don't see why you need the negative look ahead here. And as you put `?` after the `\\*` and don't test for word or string boundary, this seems useless.

Comment: @dystroy I removed the lookahead just to simplify. and the `?` after the `\*` is for searching if the string ends with `*` or not....( later i inspect this value via match. my whole question iwas why the test is fails. and it was the double slashing issue. thanks.

Comment: @dystroy so if i want to search a dot -- will this be ok ? `[0-9\\._a-z-]` ?

Comment: You don't need to escape the dot between `[]`. And you probably should use a regex literal.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I think I now get what you wanted. Note that you might be missing a word boundary (`\b` escaped as `\\b` in a string literal) or a string end (`$`).